# Dojo Filtering Select - how to program

Tags: dojo, xpages, filtering

I've not programmed this before and I'm not finding any examples in searching of how to implement this Dojo.

I need a field to type ahead as a drop down field and will fill in the field as they type so when they type enough characters for their needs, they can hit enter and it grabs the correct value.  My view is over the 64K limit.  The field I've programmed, when previewing in the browser, doesn't show the field, only values in a huge long list below it.  Can someone shed some light on how to program this field?  Thanks for your help.

Is there an reference book that give examples of all the various elements of xPages that go into more detail than, for example, loading a drop down with six values.

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 1):

Is this the Dojo Filtering Select Extension Library control? If so, XPages Extension Library book covers those components. Mastering XPages 2nd Edition covers the core controls and generic XPages runtime topics.

Without code or more details it's hard to tell what the cause is. It sounds like the relevant Dojo classes aren't loaded. That could be because the theme used is Bootstrap, which is jQuery-based rather than Dojo-based. Alternatively, if you're not using the Extension Library control, the most likely cause is declaring the Dojo Filtering Select but not including the relevant Dojo modules. That's again one of the reasons to use the Extension Library components instead of manually coding them. Alternatively you may be using a modern IE browser against an older Domino version - IE doesn't support older versions of Dojo, requiring compatible browser / server versions.

Comment: I got the type ahead to work but it's acting very strange.  It seems like it's searching on any part of the first column in the view which is a concatenation of Customer name and City so the user can indicate the drop ship for the order.  How do I only search for a key but have the drop down show more data than the key?  It's also showing a rambling of symbols like part of the display is a symbol font.  Has anyone seen this?

Comment: You should be able to choose a different column as the key. If you want a more flexible layout, look at the answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286096/specialized-type-ahead

Comment: How do I choose a column for the key?  This is a combo box you realize, not an Editbox with type ahead.

Comment: The options for all of the select controls can be computed and can use key/value pairs or the same options for both key and value. So instead of pointing the options to the first column for both key and value, point to the first column for value and a different column for key. You can create the relevant Java/SSJS objects, depending on which component you're using, or define a separator. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532641/populating-selectitems-of-the-combobox-label-value-using-a-managed-bean
If you want more flexible formatting, you'll need to use an Edit Box with typeahead.

Comment: In SSJS, `javax.faces.model.SelectItem` is the class you need

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but if that's the class I need, how do I get it?  How do I apply it and where is it?

Comment: SSJS example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361013/use-ssjs-only-to-populate-dojo-combo-box-and-include-separate-itemlabel-and-item